# How to share a session with a php application

Tags: php, django, cookies, django-sessions

I have a django blog project and a chat in PHP.

I need to share the id of the user logged in django ( request.user.id ) with the chat in PHP.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think using sessions in this way is a good idea, since they're designed to keep data temporarily for a certain user in an application. It might be a better idea to store the id in a cookie and read that in the chat, or pass a variable in the link.

Comment: If I save the user id in the cookies then some lamers ( or hacker ) can edit it and chatting with another username and another friendslist ( because for every user id there are a certain friendlist ).

Comment: Of course you'd need to include some kind of hash to make sure it's legit. The same thing can happen with sessions by the way. Something like `md5($userid."salt".time())` will work, then check that later, include the IP of the user if you wish.

Comment: Wow, so it's that simple. Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTTP authentication for this. As long as both applications are on the same domain and the realm name (sent in the WWW-Authenticate header) is the same for both, once a use logs into one or the other application, the REMOTE_USER variable will be available to both and will contain the username of the person logged in.

Comment: That would work, but for most people HTTP authentication will be out of place compared to the usual HTML form auth.

Answer (score 0):

See http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/a492cb9394b0db4d for one answer